# How to add a font awesome icon dynamically in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I have two inputs positioned in a modal and a button that generates two more inputs when the user clicks on it. It works but I want to add a font awesome icon next to the two inputs only for the dynamically created inputs, how can I achieve this in Vue? Here is my code so far:

```html
<div class="price-round-creation-containe" v-for="(shareholder, index) in shareholders" :key="index">
  <div>
    <input v-model="shareholder.username" :name="`shareholders[${index}][username]`" type="text" class="form-control input" >
  </div>
  <div>
    <input v-model="shareholder.investment" :name="`shareholders[${index}][investment]`" type="text" class="form-control input" >
  </div>
</div>

<p
  class="add-new-shareholders-p"
  @click="createNewPricedRoundShareholder"
>
  <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg" />ADD NEW SHAREHOLDER
</p>
```

my data:

```
shareholders: [
  {
    investment: "Investment",
    username: "Username"
  },
]
```

and the function for my add button:

```
createNewPricedRoundShareholder() {
 this.shareholders.push({
    username: "Username",
    investment: "Investment"
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an extra property `dynamic: true` to the additions:

```js
this.shareholders.push({
  username: "Username",
  investment: "Investment",
  dynamic: true
})
```

and check for it when showing the inputs:

```html
<div>
   <input v-model="shareholder.username" :name="`shareholders[${index}][username]`" type="text" class="form-control input" >
   <i v-if="shareholder.dynamic" class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg" />
</div>
<div>
   <input v-model="shareholder.investment" :name="`shareholders[${index}][investment]`" type="text" class="form-control input" >
   <i v-if="shareholder.dynamic" class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg" />
</div>
```